# Bootstrap does not load into my laravel project through building assets

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

This is because I am having problems with **npm run dev**.

I don't get any errors but I don't get the "*webpack compiled successfully*" message when I run npm run dev.

Here's what the terminal screen looks like when I run the command:

[image]

It crashes as shown in the screenshot without getting "webpack compiled successfully".
What do you advise me to do?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @WhoDoYouthinkami I don't get any errors, just that the command doesn't complete with the success message

Comment: that's strange did you install everything required? Which documentation / video you following?

Comment: Yes, I just did **npm install** first; later i did **npm install bootstrap**. Once this is done, after I imported the file in app.css I started laravel-mix with the command **npm run dev**